# error:no appropriate constructor found, even though i have made one,c++

Tags: c++

```
class String
{
    private:
        static const int SZ = 80;
        char str[SZ];
    public:
        String()
        {
            strcpy_s(str, " ");
        }
        String(char s[])
        {
            strcpy_s(str, s);
        }
}
```

This is the constructor i have written, note the second one

and here I am using it:

```
String s1 = "yes";
String s2 = "no";
String s3;
```

This is the error message :

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error
>   (active)  E0415   no suitable constructor exists to convert from  "const
>   char [4]" to "String"  rishabh c++ projects   F:\rishabh c++
>   projects\rishabh c++ projects\main.cpp 35

Comment: Note the error message said `const char[4]`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The compiler is telling you there is no implicit cast from your string literal to any of the available constructors.  The reason behind this is the types that your class *can* be constructed with:

```
String(char s[]);
```

Note that string literals are constant, as per the C++ standard.  That will *not* be implicitly converted to the non-constant type that your constructor requires.  To do that would require `const_cast`, but please don't do that!!!

You would also get an error (or at least a warning) if you attempted explicit construction:

```
String s1("yes");  // error
```

The simple fix is the change the parameter to `const char[]` (or indeed `const char*` is more commonly used).

```
String(const char *s)
{
    strcpy_s(str, s);
}
```

Whenever passing pointer or reference types as parameters, always ask yourself: *"does my function need to modify the value of the parameter?"* -- whenever the answer is *"no"* make it `const`.